# Cross compiling raspberry pi

Tags: c++, cmake, arm, g++, cross-compiling

i want to cross-compile a program for my raspberry pi. I decided to use the arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc-7 compiler, copy /usr and /lib/ to my host into the directory ~/raspberrypi/rootfs and set up a cmake configurated as follows:

```
SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)
SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION 1)

SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH $ENV{HOME}/raspberrypi/rootfs)
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)

# Specify the cross compiler
SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc-7)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++-7)
```

everything is working fine until i run make, then i get the error:

```
/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/include/sys/cdefs.h:467:49: error: missing binary operator before token "("
#if __GNUC_PREREQ (4,8) || __glibc_clang_prereq (3,5)
                                                 ^
```

and some more of the same type...

Does anyone has an idea of what is going wrong there?

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Since `cmake` is involved, it could make sense to add its tag. Also if you could add the command line `cmake` divined for your system and `make` actually ran, it might provide further clues. You can also try running the same thing, but stop after `cpp` is done with your source file. I suspect something went pear shape at that point, looking at my `features.h`, unless `__clang_major__` and `__clang_minor__` are defined (presumably that would be the case when using `clang`) it the macro would be: `#define __glibc_clang_prereq(maj, min) 0` -> read harmless and could not yield the same error.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe your include paths is missing the (correct) `features.h`

I ran into the same error when cross compiling witgh QTCreator using Qt 5.15 for Raspberry Pi.

Adding `INCLUDEPATH += somepath/sysroot/usr/include` in the pro file fixed it. That is, add the `/usr/include` of the target machine to your include path. (Use the correct sysroot path on your system, of course...)